# mongo slow query

Tags: performance, mongodb

My mongodb is currently loaded with 105,000 documents, and I still have to insert 500,000 more, and it is taking more than 4hours just to insert 1000 documents, due to querying for references:

Insert DocA, and DocA have many citations (about 30)
Find documents in the database which are cited by DocA. [ie: findBy-Doi-Or-Pmid-Or-Pmc(...)]

-so for each of the query for DocA's citation, it is taking about 400ms to complete.

following is one of the profile:
Query { $or [ {$or [ {doi: ""}, {pmid: "10508155"} ] }, {pmc: "" } ]}

```
{
   "ts": ISODate("2012-12-22T11: 55: 39.796Z"),
   "op": "query",
   "ns": "fyparticles.mArticle",
   "query": {
     "$or": {
       "0": {
         "$or": {
           "0": {
             "doi": "" 
          },
           "1": {
             "pmid": "10508155" 
          } 
        } 
      },
       "1": {
         "pmc": "" 
      } 
    } 
  },
   "ntoreturn": NumberInt(1),
   "nscanned": NumberInt(105707),
   "responseLength": NumberInt(20),
   "millis": NumberInt(477),
   "client": "192.168.0.15",
   "user": "" 
}
```

And the index I have created:

```
{
   "v": NumberInt(1),
   "key": {
     "doi": NumberInt(1),
     "pmid": NumberInt(1),
     "pmc": NumberInt(1) 
  },
   "ns": "fyparticles.system.indexes",
   "background": NumberInt(1),
   "name": "params" 
}
```

Please help me out here! Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Comment: try to fix formatting and try to get more clarification about what you need

Answer (score 2):

First off you are using an `$or` which in itself is not the fastest operator in the world due to its need to run multiple queries and then merge duplicates to return a result.

Second you are using an `$or` with one index. Since an `$or` is basically one or more queries you may need one or more indexes to cover the unique fields you have in each clause.

Third you are using nested `$or`s it is good to note that nested `$or`s do not use indexes: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3327

So already you have like 3 or more performance problems with your query.

first off, take out that nested `$or`:

```
 { $or: [  {doi: ""}, {pmid: "10508155"}, {pmc: ""} ] }
```

And then you will probably need to create three indexes on this (you might be able to get one to fit all I haven't tested):

```
db.col.ensureIndex({ doi: 1 });
db.col.ensureIndex({ pmdi: 1 });
db.col.ensureIndex({ pmc: 1 });
```

That should be the first place to start to make your query faster.

Comment: Wow yes, thanks for the tip! Apparently I got my query from using Spring data - findByDoiOrPmidOrPmc() gave me the 2 $or, which was pretty bad and slow ><. I had it reworked as you had said, no more $or, and index accordingly. :D swift. thank you!

Comment: @user1665302 Ah yea sometimes it is better to build your own queries :) I personally don't trust automated builders, anyway glad to have helped